# Unity shortcut hint overlay doesn't show up

Tags: unity-2d

The Unity shortcut hint overlay should show up when I long press the Super(Win) key on my keyboard. But in my case, it doesn't. It was there when I first install 12.04, but now, it doesn't show up at all. The launcher is perfectly working (I hope). I'm logged into Unity 2D, do you think it might have to do with that? If so, is there a solution that the overlay would still work even in Unity 2D?

Answer (score 1):

The shortcut doesn't work on Unity 2d.